# How to condense summable metrics to a unique identifier in a ruby table

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to condense summable metrics to a unique identifier in a ruby table.

I have the following table:

```
[["id1", 123], ["id2", 234], ["id1", 345]]
```

What's the most effective way to condense the metrics such that it will look like this:

```
[["id1", 468], ["id2", 234]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the other answerers are overthinking this. You can do this with just one operation, `each_with_object`, and a Hash:

```
metrics = [["id1", 123], ["id2", 234], ["id1", 345]]

metrics.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |(id, val), sums|
  sums[id] += val
end
# => {"id1"=>468, "id2"=>234}
```

If you want an Array instead of a Hash at the end just call `to_a` on the result, but there are few compelling reasons to do so.

Comment: How would this change if there were 3 elements per row and you could sum both the 2nd and 3rd elements per unique id?

Comment: That depends on what you want the result to look like. [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) is pretty straightforward; if you're having a specific problem writing code that yields the results you want I suggest posting a new question.

Comment: Hrm having a difficult time with more than one column. I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452654/how-to-sum-multiple-elements-of-nested-arrays-on-unique-keys

Answer (score 1):

As condensed as it can get.

```
array = [["id1", 123],["id2", 234], ["id1", 345]]
array.group_by(&:first).collect{|key,values| [key,values.reduce(0) {|sum,a| sum+a[1]}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
summable_metrics = [["id1", 123],["id2", 234], ["id1", 345]]

summable_metrics.group_by(&:first).map do |k, v|
  [k, v.map(&:last).reduce(:+)]
end

=> [["id1", 468], ["id2", 234]]
```