# How to sum multiple elements of nested arrays on unique keys

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have the following defined table. The index for each element in each row corresponds to the same field.

```
[[123.0, 23,"id1",34, "abc"], 
 [234.1,43, "id2", 24,"jsk"],
 [423.5,53, "id1",1,"xyz"],
 [1.4, 5, "id2",0,"klm"]]
```

In the above example I need to group and sum an output that sums each of the summable elements on the index for the unique identifier in the 3rd column. The result should look like this:

```
[[546.5,76, "id1",35],
 [235.5,48, "id2",24]]
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: If you can show how you have done it, then, others can comment on how to improve it.  Please note that if you need your code to be reviewed, you may have to post to [Code review exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially the same as the solution to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37450179/179125).

```
data = [ [ 123.0, 23, "id1", 34, "abc" ], 
         [ 234.1, 43, "id2", 24, "jsk" ],
         [ 423.5, 53, "id1",  1, "xyz" ],
         [   1.4,  5, "id2",  0, "klm" ] ]

sums = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [0, 0, 0] }

data.each_with_object(sums) do |(val0, val1, id, val2, _), sums|
  sums[id][0] += val0
  sums[id][1] += val1
  sums[id][2] += val2
end
# => { "id1" => [ 546.5, 76, 35 ],
#      "id2" => [ 235.5, 48, 24 ] }
```

The main difference is that instead of giving the Hash a default value of `0`, we're giving it a default proc that initializes missing keys with `[0, 0, 0]`. (We can't just do `Hash.new([0, 0, 0])` because then every value would be a reference to a single Array instance, rather than each value having its own Array.) Then, inside the block, we add each value (`val0` et al) to the corresponding elements of `sums[id]`.

If you wanted an Array of Arrays instead of a Hash with the `id` at index 2, then at the end, you would have to add something like this:

```
.map {|id, vals| vals.insert(2, id) }
```

However, a Hash with the ids as keys makes more sense as a data structure.

Comment: sorry was making an update to the problem

Comment: I see what you're doing here though, this makes more sense as I didn't really understand the concept of `.each_with_object`

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect your changes.